# fetch_message(id) with user token

Tags: discord.py

make `await fetch_message(id)` work with user token

`client.run((token), bot=False)`

I'm trying to get a bot that uses a user's token to respond to a message by id i try use `await fetch_message(id)` but i got:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\edgar\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 20, in on_message
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(826185450141253682)
  File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1002, in fetch_message
    data = await self._state.http.get_message(channel.id, id)
  File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 20002): Only bots can use this endpoint
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do, add your code and the errors you face. I do not really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: ok i done its better?

Comment: Well, the error now is self-explanatory as only bots can do what you are trying to do.

Comment: So I'm asking for another way to do it

Comment: So you want to grab a users token and then respond with that account to a message?

Comment: no just press reaction

Comment: Maybe it can be done in another language?

Comment: You are using your own peroneal token not a bot token. You can't do that action with a user token.

Comment: I've seen someone do this before

Comment: It's not allowed. Period. Idk where you've seen someone do this before, but it's not allowed. Even if you could make the API calls, self bots are against [Discord's ToS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE This workaround only works if your selfbot was running at the point the message where send.

you can use the cached_mesages attribute from the discord Client.

```
messages = client.cached_messages
# and then use the utils.get function to seek for the id in this list
message = discord.utils.get(messages, id=id_to_seek)

#  utils.get() returns None if message not found
#  else it returnes a normal Message object you can work with.
```

I never tried this on a selfbot, but this prevents you from making the API call and should work just as expected.